SharePoint 2013 session timeout error after SQL Server started running in a Microsoft Cluster
We have a SharePoint 2013 site that is giving a session timeout error or an error related to the session object reference not being set to an instance of an object. The issue started when SQL Server began running in a Microsoft cluster as we had two sql db servers and now it is clustered.
IISRESET is done no code change happened want to understand the root cause please help on this.
